# Problems rendering dropdown menu over HTML5 video

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, video, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a drop down menu which appears at the top of the page, just above a HTML5 video. I've noticed, so far on Chrome and Safari, that this sometimes results in some weird rending of the drop down menu.

[image: HTML5 video and drop down menu rendering problem]

It seems to be triggered when you scroll up and down, then click the menu. The video is embedded using the HTML5  tag, and the menu is built using Bootstrap 3's drop down support.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Please show us some code. Additionally a live preview wouldn't be that bad.

Comment: Unfortunately the site isn't online and I'm not really sure how useful the code would be, since it's only a HTML5 video and the CSS for the navbar/dropdown is from Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Okay, you're right code maybe not so useful, because it looks like a rendering issue. But wouldn't it be possible to make a small minor replicate on jsfiddle.net. It would be a lot easier to help then.

Comment: No worries, I'll see if I can recreate the problem on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to using a negative z-index for the video container.

As I wanted the video to appear in the background, I gave it a negative z-index. For some reason, when the video element had a negative z-index, the dropdown menu above was having rendering issues as shown in the question screenshot. Moving the video to have a positive z-index (albeit, a lower z-index than the other page elements, so it still appears in the background) seems to have resolved the issue.